# How to work with dynamic container in Isotope?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

In the context of re-using an Isotope container on different parts of a web application, I need to resize the container. However, after adding and removing a CSS class for small layout, the container is not anymore taking up the full space.

See the JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/mulderp/ptLzx/5/

```
$container.addClass('small');
```

This resizes the container as expected.

```
 $container.removeClass('small');
 $container.isotope('shuffle');
```

Expected would be to get back the original container. This does not work.

Any clues how to get the setup working?

Comment: You add a class small but you remove large, which is not existing? Shouldn't it be: $container.removeClass('small'); ?

Comment: right, the fiddle has a problem. This is the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/mulderp/ptLzx/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a timing issue, this tends to happen a lot with Isotope.

If you put a setTimeout() of 1000ms around the shuffle method it works - therefore confirming the issue...

```
$('#large').click(function(){
    $container.removeClass('small');
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $container.isotope('shuffle');      
    },1000);
});
```

The timeout is not ideal at all, but it does illustrate that Isotope needs to be finished before it can be updated. I would recommend testing with different timers until you find a nice fit.

I would also recommend using `$container.isotope('reLayout')` over `$container.isotope('shuffle')` unless you specifically need to shuffle the items, that method was created for doing exactly this.

Comment: very helpful... I'll explore that route!